# Wordpress API V2 custom fields with custom post types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I'm trying to add my custom posts to the Wordpress API, which also have custom fields.

I can view the custom posts types on the API via, `/wp-json/wp/v2/fruit`.

But the custom fields aren't displaying, how do you add them to the API?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-to-rest-api/

Comment: or thats the way I did it - there might be others, but this was literally at the click of a button.

Comment: @Stender that didn't work for me, i'm not using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at "[Extending the REST API / Modifying Responses](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/)", and in particular at [`register_rest_field`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#adding-custom-fields-to-api-responses).

Check out [this example](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_field/#comment-2145):

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'create_api_posts_meta_field' );

function create_api_posts_meta_field() {

    // register_rest_field ( 'name-of-post-type', 'name-of-field-to-return', array-of-callbacks-and-schema() )
    register_rest_field( 'post', 'post-meta-fields', array(
           'get_callback'    => 'get_post_meta_for_api',
           'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}

function get_post_meta_for_api( $object ) {
    //get the id of the post object array
    $post_id = $object['id'];

    //return the post meta
    return get_post_meta( $post_id );
}
```